# Using Undead Mounts

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, mount

I am playing a character and eventually plan on having an undead mount.

I was not able to find any specific rules on what was required for a mount beyond them generally having to be at least one size category larger. There are lists of purchasable mounts in both [equipment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/animals-animal-gear) and [ride skill](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/ride). As there is a [skeleton mount](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeleton-medium/skeleton-mount/) listed in the bestiary they are possible, but no mention is made to the rules for them. So must all mounts come from these lists?

When you ride an undead mount for long distance and using the hustle/run/forced march where checks are required, would the rider be making these checks or only the mount, or both?

Are there any other aspects that I might have overlooked? Yes, I know undead are evil, and that they dont eat, sleep, or breath. Handle animal does not work (because they are mindless unless a higher form of undead), but the mount will be under some form of control.

Comment: I'm a little confused what your actual question is? A pro/con list of undead mounts? Specifically about long distance travel? Are they even allowed (which would be additionally confusing since you already reference one in the books)?

Comment: @Ifusaso Who makes movement checks, mount and/or rider? Are there special rules about undead mounts because I saw references to ones from 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mounts listed as purchasable are standard, but seeing as how in pathfinder any undead immediately qualify as being evil it may be difficult to find one.  They're also hardier than normal mounts and that would be sure to drive up the price. It would largely depend on whether your gm is okay with it. All searches I did on it seem to suggest it's largely something that needs to be created, such as taking a horse corpse and using a spell to raise it as a skeleton or zombie.

> Mounted movement: A mount bearing a rider can move at a hustle. The damage it takes when doing so is lethal not non-lethal.  The creature can also be ridden in a forced march but its con checks automatically fail and the damage it takes is lethal. Mounts also become fatigued when they take any damage from hustling or forced marches.(Pathfinder Core rule book pg. 171)

From the text on the rules it sounds like only the mount makes the checks.

Comment: Was not planning on purchasing an undead as a mount, as in game that would be impossible. I was planning on using a large humanoid and having my feet on top of the hip bones while holding the collarbones for support. Or some fast dino.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.